# Adding a view dynamically in a ClickListener

Tags: android

I am trying to add a View to a RelativeLayout in my OnClickListener.

```
 montrolButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
// myParent is a relative layout
// newChild is an ImageView
                     myParent.addView(newChild);
                     requestLayout();
                 }
});
```

I have looked at the HierarchyViewer, I don' see my new child being added.
Can you please tell me if I miss anything?

Comment: I think you need to add setContentView(myParent);

Comment: It should work the way you do it (if `myParent` is part of your layout-hierarchy). Did you refresh HierarchyViewer after adding the child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the very same code and it works as it should. There could be an issue with your variable `myParent` which is not the element you expect it to be.

Also I did not have to call `requestLayout()` for the added view to appear on the screen.

Possibly try to just explicitly get another part of your view and add it there to see what is happening. Also just to try, you may do this:

```
    RelativeLayout rv = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.right3);
    ProgressBar iv = new ProgressBar(this);
    rv.addView(iv);
```

to see if there is anything wrong with your image view instead of myParent

In any case it works if both elements are OK - there is nothing else to do in an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the layout attributes of the new view (image view)?